# ERROR The method getId() is undefined for the type

Tags: maven, maven-2, aspectj, spring-roo

I have an application which use AspectJ and Spring Roo. I have no experience  with these technologies. During a building by Maven (3.3.9
) I got an error in a console:

```
im@im:~/projects/maintenance$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maintenance 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maintenance ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) @ maintenance ---
[ERROR] The method getId() is undefined for the type Employee
```

and the error is fair, because I really don't have `getId()` method in `Employee` class but I have these annotations:

```
import ...

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(persistenceUnit = "entityManagerFactoryMaintenance", identifierField = "id", identifierColumn = "EMPLOYEE_ID", versionColumn = "", versionField = "", finders = { "findEmployeesByHireDateIsNull" }, mergeMethod = "", persistMethod = "", removeMethod = "")
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES"/*, schema = Constants.ORACLE_MAINTENANCE_SCHEMA*/)
public class Employee {..}
```

I guess that the problem somewhere in AspectJ. Here is my `pom.xml` sections which contain AspectJ:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.1</aspectj.version>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <roo.version>1.3.1.RC1</roo.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    ...
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <!-- NB: do not use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 and do not use 1.4 
                due to declare parents issue -->
            <dependencies>
                <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see 
                    MNG-2972) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                            <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                        </arguments>
                    </buildCommand>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also I'm not sure about IDE. I use IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) on Ubuntu. Is this so important to use Eclipse?

What can I do built the app?

Comment: Why don't you try the current AspectJ Maven plugin version 1.11? Who told you to use a version released in 2009? And why the Maven Eclipse plugin if you don't use Maven? Your POM looks really strange. I recommend to start with something not copied & pasted from what seems too be a super old source. At the time that POM was written the current Java version was 6 (now 12), Spring Roo didn't exist - and who still uses Maven 2?

Comment: This is legacy code. And to update it to current versions I need to build and start it, first of all. As it.

Comment: Of course it is legacy code. I said so, too. But Spring Roo is not legacy, at least not that old. So obviously you have means to upgrade components in your build and runtime management. Just apply that option to AspectJ Maven, Maven itself and possibly other plugins, too. I don't know if it helps, but you need to start cleaning up somewhere, eliminating possible error sources. As you said, you want to build and start it. So upgrade your build system! Then build it.

Comment: You use Java 8, AspectJ 1.8.1 - not new, but not super old. Why use outdated plugins which maybe don't know options of newer Java or AspectJ versions? Besides, the current AspectJ version is 1.9.4, the last 1.8 version is 1.8.14. You are missing a lot of bugfixes since 1.8.1. P.S.: If you ploade an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem to HitHub for me (private repo is okay), I can take a look.